# Is it possible to preview an Android XML on a website?

Tags: android, xml, adt

I am trying to parse an Android XML to be shown on a website. Is it possible?

I know ADT for [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) does it, but I need the code to show it on my website.

Is there any API to render an Android XML file as HTML?

Comment: Why do you need to show it on a website? Would a screenshot suffice?

Comment: Because I want to make an Android layout previewer

Comment: Its definitively possible, you would just need to do a lot of re-engineering.